# How do I enable editing of entries with a front-end form?

Tags: entries, form, frontend

Users can currently submit entries using a form on the front-end. How would I go about showing the current logged in user's existing entries and allow them to edit them through another front-end form?

Answer (score 4):

Add another hidden input field "entryId" to your form. There's nice [example code in the Docs](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entry-form#editing-entry-form):

> You can modify the form to save existing entries by adding an “entryId” hidden input to the form:
>
> ```
> <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">
> ```

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I can't make sense of it. Users currently post entries using a form in jobs/new/index.html. The entry is viewed with jobs/{slug}. How would I go about passing the entryId into a form inside jobs/edit/index.html so users can view and edit changes? I'm pretty lost, sorry if this is confusing.

Comment: There are a number of ways to accomplish this. One way is to just request the same template `jobs/{slug}` but with a post or get variable 'edit', then test for the variable in the template and instead of the normal content, deliver a pre-populated form. Another would be to send the `entry.id` using post or get to the edit form, which would set the hidden field (and populate the fields). If you need an example, let us know.

Comment: I've got the form working and this is how I've done it. I've got an edit link leading to jobs/edit/{{ entry.id }} and inside my edit template I've included this in the form:
<input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ craft.request.getSegment(3) }}">

This is working and I can edit and save an entry, however prepopulating the form with {%- if entry is defined %} value="{{ entry.title }}"{% endif -%} doesn't work at all. Any idea why?

Comment: @Jamie because the template is not set in the section settings, you don't get a var `entry` pre-populated. So you have to set it yourself: `{% set entry = craft.entries.id(craft.request.getSegment(3)).first() %}` or better, set a var `id` first: `{% set id = craft.request.getSegment(3) %}` and then get the entry model with `{% set entry = craft.entries.id(id).first() %}`.